# How to access CreateNasDatastore in the vmware sdk?

Tags: perl, vmware

I'm trying to use the Vmware Perl SDK to mount an nfs datastore, and the docs are...challenging...but while I thought I had it worked out, I get:

Can't locate object method "CreateNasDatastore" via package "ManagedObjectReference" at ./mkds line 65.

I've updated to the latest Perl SDK (6.7) as well...

According to https://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.DatastoreSystem.html

CreateNasDatastore is a method in the Managed Object HostDatastoreSystem, which is a property of HostConfigManager, so for each host, I get the HostSystem view and then use the configManager->datastoreSystem object:

```
...
foreach my $host_view (@$host_views) {
...
    print "connected to $host\n";

    my $cf_views = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type => 'HostSystem');
    foreach my $cfv (@$cf_views) {
        my $ds = $cfv->configManager->datastoreSystem;
        print Dumper($ds);
        # no arguments yet, just trying to find out how to invoke it
        $ds->CreateNasDatastore();
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

```
connected to vcenter01.ad.casco.net
Hosts found:
1: cvo-esx5.ad.casco.net
connected to cvo-esx5.ad.casco.net
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'value' => 'ha-datastoresystem',
                 'type' => 'HostDatastoreSystem'
               }, 'ManagedObjectReference' );
Can't locate object method "CreateNasDatastore" via package "ManagedObjectReference" at ./mkds line 65.
```

I'm not sure how else to access it, and hoping someone else understands this structure better than I do...

Answer (score 1):

The document you link to is not about a Perl SDK, and it's possible that the Perl bindings would look slightly different (different case conventions, different order of inputs, stuff like that) or even very different from the bindings for another language.

So here's a general tip. To see the methods supported by the `ManagedObjectReference` tip, inspect the stash variable `%ManagedObjectReference::`.

```
print "Symbols in 'ManagedObjectReference' namespace:\n\t";
print join("\n\t", sort keys %ManagedObjectReference::);
```

That will list the symbols in the namespace, some of which will be method names, and maybe they will give you a hint about the correct spelling of the method you are looking for.

Comment: ManagedObjectReference is just a base class: ```Symbols in 'ManagedObjectReference' namespace:
 BEGIN
 ISA
 deserialize
 get_property_list
 property_list
 serialize
 type```

Comment: I poked around in the perl modules, and CreateNasDatastore is in VIM25Runtime, which was included in the latest 6.7 SDK, but when I use it instead of VIRuntime, I get ```Use of inherited AUTOLOAD for non-method Opts::get_option() is deprecated at /usr/share/perl5/VMware/VICommon.pm line 440.
connected to vcenter01.ad.casco.net
Vim::find_entity_view called, but no global session is defined at ./mkds line 34.```

Comment: Further investigation found that VIRuntime checks the server sdk version (apparently 2.5) and loads VIM25Runtime itself, so this was a red herring

Answer (score 0):

> I found that some of the command line tools installed with the SDK are perl, and found this solution in vicfg-nas (it shows how to build the argument structure too):

```
use VMware::VIRuntime;
use VMware::VIExt;
...
eval {
    Vim::login( user_name => $esx_user, password => $esx_pw, service_url => "https://$server/sdk");
};
...
my $datacenter_view = Vim::find_entity_view(view_type => 'Datacenter');
my $host_views = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type => 'HostSystem',
                                        begin_entity => $datacenter_view);
foreach my $host_view (@$host_views) {
    my $host = $host_view->{'name'};
    eval {
        Vim::login( user_name => $esx_user, password => $esx_pw, service_url => "https://$host/sdk");
    };

    my $ds_view = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $host_view->{'configManager.datastoreSystem'});

    my $hostNasVolSpec = new HostNasVolumeSpec (remoteHost => $fileserver, 
                                               remotePath => $share, 
                                               localPath => $label,
                                               accessMode => $accessMode); 
    $ds_view->CreateNasDatastore(spec => $hostNasVolSpec);
}
```